# Why quotient map maps open sets to open sets?

Tags: general-topology

My book says that the quotient map of a topological space $X$ into its equivalence classes under some equivalence relation maps open sets to open sets.However my intuition tells me that this is wrong for the following reason.Let the situation be as above and suppose the set of points in $X$ forming one equivalence class is not open, name this set $C$.Now suppose you can find an open subset $U$ of $C$. Then $f(U)$ is just the equivalence class we started with. To decide if $f(U)$ is open by definition we must have $f^{-1}f(U)$ is open but it is not since it is the set $C$ which by construction is not open.

What am I saying wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It maps open $\sim$-saturated sets to open sets.

Comment: Your argument is fine. Does your book make special assumptions about the equivalence classes?

Comment: i miss something $f:X\to...$

Comment: No it does not, actually it's just some printed notes that a student gave me. I guess the notes are just wrong then

Comment: @user142775 The open sets in $X/{\sim}$ are precisely those which are open viewed in $X$.